# Python error about "malformed node or string" in matrix

Tags: python, arrays, string, matrix

I am using a matrix:

```
D = np.matrix('-1j 0 0 0; 0 1j 0 0; 0 0 (1-1j)/np.sqrt(2) 0;0 0 0 (1+1j)/np.sqrt(2)')
```

However, Python says that

> ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.BinOp object at 0x0000015B0FC279A0>

However, the following can work

```
(1+1j)/np.sqrt(2)
```

Can anyone please let me know how to fix it? thanks!

Comment: You have apparently exceeded numpy's ability to parse numeric expressions out of a string.  Try supplying the values as actual numbers, in the form of a list of lists.